# Jboss Drools- It is possible to write two or more conditions (in WHEN block )in single rule?

Tags: drools

It is possible to write two or more conditions in a single rule ?

i.e in WHEN block write multiple conditons ?

Comment: Yes, see the Drools documentation, or provide more material in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. if they are AND conditions you can write as many as you want, check the docs. 
If they are OR conditions is usually recommended to split the rule into many rules, just for the sake of simplicity.